# Constant series: generalisation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given is the series $(a_n)$ defined by $a_{n+1}=-3a_n+4$.
 a) Show that there is a value of $a_0$, let's denote it $k$, for which $(a_n)$ is constant.

b) Show that the series $(b_n)$ defined by $b_n=a_n-k$ is geometric.

I answered both questions, but is there a generalisation possible?

Comment: What do you mean with a generalisation? For any sequence $a_{n+1} = Ba_n + C$ with $B,C$ arbitrary constants?

Comment: @SteamyRoot yes for example

Comment: Well for $a_{n+1}=Ba_n+C$ you get $k=Bk+C$ and $k(1-B)=C$ so $k=\frac{C}{1-B}$

Answer (score 0):

$k=1$. Equivalently, you start from $a_0$, $a_1$ and $a_{n+2}=-2a_{n+1}+3a_n$. the characteristic polynomial is
$$
p(z)=z^2+2z-3=(z-1)(z+3),
$$
hence the solutions will be of the form $\alpha (-3)^n+\beta$, for some constant $\alpha,\beta$, and the same for $(b_n)$. Setting $n=0$ and $n=1$ we obtain
$$
b_0=a_0-1=\alpha+\beta
$$
and
$$
b_1=a_1-1=-3a_0+3=-3(a_0-1)=-3\alpha+\beta.
$$
In particular, $\beta=0$, which is what we wanted to prove. What kind of generalization are you searching for?

Comment: A generalization for b